# Many to Many Relationship table Not working cannot delete Value from that

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsql-package

```
declare
begin
  for i in (select aid ,address from address)
  loop
    for j in (select aid ,address from address )
    loop
      if i.address=j.address then
        if i.aid!=j.aid then
          update employee_add 
          set aid=i.aid 
          where aid=j.aid;
          delete from address 
          where aid=i.aid;
        end if;
      end if; 
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

This code works fine as `for loop`. After that it shows  error :------

> *Cause:    A foreign key value has no matching primary key value.
>   *Action:   Delete the foreign key or add a matching primary key.

I have tables `employee[eid   (primary key) ,ename]` ,`address[aid  (primary 
    key),address]`,and many to many relation table`employee_add[eid,aid]`.
            Please help! Thank in Advance :)

Comment: Using plain language, describe what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: actually i have 3 table address,employee and employee_address table where  address table has address id and address name where address id is primary key where address is duplicate address like 101-banglore 102-banglore 103-banglore 104-pune 105-pune 106-hyderbad and employee_address  has  eid and aid such as 1-101,1-102,1-103,2-101,2-101,2-104,3-102,3-103.... i want to delete duplicate data from address having same address meanwhile i want to delete address associated with employee_address such that there should not be any data loss in employee_address table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You can use only one `loop` statement and `variables`( `v_address` and `v_aid`  ) to make a comparison between the rows as in the block below :*

```
declare
  v_address address.address%type;
  v_aid     address.aid%type;  
begin
 for i in (select aid ,address from address order by aid)
 loop  
    if nvl(v_address,'')=i.address then 
         update employee_add set aid=v_aid where aid=i.aid;  
         delete address where aid=i.aid;
    else
       v_address := i.address;
       v_aid := i.aid;   
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: pls explain this ""if nvl(v_address,'')"" i am unable to understand this

Comment: @ViratSingh it's not suitable in some cases, especially for inequalities, collate directly two terms one of them is null, and the other is not null. And in the first step v_adress is still null . This is equality, but had better making this a habit for a developer I think.

Comment: can you tell me why my code only working for 1 time only because it gave the value for other loop 101 it worked fine but for other cases it showed me error like foreign key has no matching primary key i am newbie in pl sql so.. this can help me to understand it better . if you can help me out then it very good. btw thank you!!

Comment: @ViratSingh I retried the code exactly all the data which you supplied in the comment, and didn't see a problem.

Comment: it didn't worked when I kept the value null to my addresses in address table

Comment: @ViratSingh dear friend I cannot see the whole picture, but only the part shown to me and I can decide and answer depending on that part of the picture :)

Comment: with huge respect I am very happy and glad you helped me a lot thankyou sir ! hope if u had solved my problem I would have been safe for job .anyway thankyou sir